# Why std::filesystem::file_size(file) is differnt with real file-size?

Tags: c++, file, filesystems, c++17, std

```
#include<iostream>
#include<random>
#include<fstream>
#include<filesystem>

int main(){
    std::default_random_engine dre;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> uid{ 1, 100'000 };

    std::filesystem::path file("./test.txt");

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> D{ std::make_unique<int[]>(10'000) };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10'000; ++i)
        D[i] = uid(dre);

    std::ofstream out(file, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    out.write((char*)D.get(), sizeof(int) * 10'000);

    std::cout << sizeof(int) * 10'000 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::filesystem::file_size(file) << std::endl;
    // should be same.
}
```

I expected the result will be same.
But the result is

```
40000
36864
```

When I checked the `test.txt` file in window, the size is 40'000. that is what I expected.
But while runtime, something I can't understand is happening. why `std::filesystem::file_size(file)` is less than real file size?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, thank u. I understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::ofstream` buffers its output, so it is possible (even likely) that by the time you are calling `file_size()`, there are still bytes in the buffer that `ofstream` has not written to the actual file yet.

Close the `ofstream` first:

```cpp
std::ofstream out(file, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
out.write((char*)D.get(), sizeof(int) * 10'000);
out.close();

std::cout << std::filesystem::file_size(file) << std::endl;
```

Or, at least call [`flush()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush) on it:

```cpp
std::ofstream out(file, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
out.write((char*)D.get(), sizeof(int) * 10'000);
out.flush();

std::cout << std::filesystem::file_size(file) << std::endl;
```